# Taking the average of many N sized arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

Can anyone help me fix this? I'm trying to write a script that takes the sum of many N sized arrays. In the example below the average of the arrays would be `(1,2)` since `(0+1+2+1)/4 = 1` and `(2+3+2+1)/4 = 2`. Currently the code below only works for arrays of size 2. How would I do this with arrays of say size 100 such that the length of @results is 100? I imagine I would need a counter right?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @w = (0, 2);
my @x = (1, 3);
my @y = (2, 2);
my @z = (1, 1);

my @arrays = \(@w, @x, @y, @z);

my ($x, $y) = (0, 0);
foreach my $arr(@arrays) {
    $x += $arr->[0];
    $y += $arr->[1];
}

my @result = ( $x / @arrays,  $y / @arrays);

print "@result\n";  # <---- prints 1 2

#######
# my attempt
my @avg;
for my $i(0..$w) {
    # I'm guessing the result 'map...' returns is an array
    @avg[$i] = sum(\(map $_->[$i], @arrays)) / @arrays;    
}    

# sum the elements in an array and return its value
sub sum{
# takes 1 param: an arrey_ref
    my $sum = 0;
    for ( @{$_[0]} ) {
    $sum += $_;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

My attempt is close but it doesn't work. I would like to do this without using a module.

Comment: all arrays are of same length?

Comment: How is this different from [*your previous question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842972)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subroutine that takes average of one or more arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842972/subroutine-that-takes-average-of-one-or-more-arrays)

Comment: @UpasanaShukla yes, the arrays are the same length

Comment: @Borodin I think the answers to this problem are more complete. it can be applied for multiple N sized arrays. We should close the other one.

Comment: This is the "tenth" time you've asked almost the same question. Maybe you should take two seconds to think about what you need before moving on...

Comment: it's actually the third time but I see your point. I will keep this in mind for future projects. thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $SIZE = 3;
my @w = (0, 2, 3);
my @x = (1, 3, 4);
my @y = (2, 2, 6);
my @z = (1, 1, 3);

my @arrays = \(@w, @x, @y, @z);

my @result = ();
foreach my $arr(@arrays) {
    for(my $i=0; $i<$SIZE; $i++) {
        $result[$i] += $arr->[$i];
    }
}

@result = map { $_ / @arrays } @result;

print "(@result)", "\n";  # <---- prints (1 2 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a simple way, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @w = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @x = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @y = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @z = (1, 2, 3, 4);

my @arrays = \(@w, @x, @y, @z);

my @sums;
foreach my $arr(@arrays) {
    for( my $i = 0; $i <= $#w; $i++, $j++ )
    {
    $sums[$j] += $arr->[$i];
    }
}

my @avg = map { $_ / @arrays } @sums;

foreach( @avg )
{
    print "$_ ";
}

print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its very close. Here are the corrections to the problem code:

```
my @avg;
for my $i (0..$#w) {
    my @transposed = map {$_->[$i]} @arrays;
    $avg[$i] = sum(\@transposed) / @transposed;
    # or in one line: $avg[$i] = sum( [map {$_->[$i]} @arrays] ) / @arrays;
}
```

(I'm assuming that the arrays `@w`, `@x`, `@y` and `@z` are all the same size.)

Note that `@avg[$i]` is an array slice. You want `$avg[$i]` to specify a particular position.

Answer (score 1):

The [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) module can be very useful for problems like this. Together with a simple `average` subroutine it makes everything very simple.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'sum';
sub average { sum(@_) / @_ }

my @w = (0, 2);
my @x = (1, 3);
my @y = (2, 2);
my @z = (1, 1);

my @arrays = \(@w, @x, @y, @z);

my @results = map {
  my $i = $_;
  average(map $_->[$i], @arrays);
} 0 .. $#{$arrays[0]};

print "@results\n";
```

**output**

```
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` does not return an array. [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)

Change

```
@avg[$i] = sum(\(map $_->[$i], @arrays)) /@arrays;
```

to

```
$avg[$i] = sum( map $_->[$i], @{$arrays[$i]} ) / @{$arrays[$i]};
```

and change

```
sub sum{
    my $sum = 0;
    for ( @{$_[0]} ) {
    $sum += $_;
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

to

```
sub sum {
    my $sum;
    $sum += $_ for @_;
    return $sum;
}
```